# Linq.DataContext to Entity.DbContext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am playing with MVC4 at the moment and ran into some issues with the Model > Controller tier.

My main model object is a `Linq To Sql` object (Auto generated) and is derived from `Linq.DataContext`,

My controller is derived from `DbDataController` and  I'm aggressively using `DbContext` everywhere.

Now I get the following error message and I am almost certain its because `DataContext` is not compatible with `DbContext`. Is there a workaround for this?

> The type 'bugsbase4.Models.BugsDataDataContext' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Web.Http.Data.EntityFramework.DbDataController'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'bugsbase4.Models.BugsDataDataContext' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.

Is it a bad practice to use Linq-to-SQL as model? Is there other ways to automatically map all the tables and stored procedures from a database without Linq-to-SQL?

**Edit**: Considered using EDM, but I am very unfamiliar with it. I feel that Linq-to-SQL has much better support for stored procedures.

Comment: MVC controller scaffolding works with EF, not LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Should I use EDM instead of LINQ to SQL then?

Comment: You should use EF 4 and above