# Confusing MVC and LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

In this tutorial http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-mvc-and-linq-to-sql-using.html they recommend using LINQ to SQL in MVC.  They then create a repository which basically makes it look more like the Entity Framework (using methods like `Add()` and `Delete()` in place of LINQ's `InsertOnSubmit()` and `DeleteOnSubmit()`.

My question is, what should I do here?  I love using LINQ but I feel it would break MVC if I abandon Entity Framework for LINQ to SQL.

LINQ to SQL generates the following line:

```
public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
```

So, I can only use methods such as `InsertOnSubmit()` and I can't use methods from Entity Framework like `Add()`.

It sounds like LINQ to Entities would be the answer, but I am not sure how that comes into play...

I have also seen the comments here [Linq.DataContext to Entity.DbContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525443/linq-datacontext-to-entity-dbcontext) which seem to imply that it's bad practice...

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is not closely tied to any OR mapper. Pick either LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework or any other suitable framework. Note that LINQ to SQL is no longer actively developed.

Comment: If LINQ to SQL is no longer being developed, is there something else that will take its place that has the same ease of use by letting you drag and drop tables and create associations visually?

Comment: Microsoft provides you with Entity Framework and you are so inclined you can use a visual designer. However, many people prefer to use the code first approach instead.

Comment: I have read about the EF Model Browser, but how do I access it?  I can access the LINQ to SQL designer by simply creating a LINQ to SQL class via "Add Class."  How can I access the EF designer?

Comment: In Visual Studio add a new item: __ADO.NET Entity Data Model__.

Comment: Even after adding the ADO.NET Entity Data Model, my code, `Title title = db.Titles.Find(id);` has error on `Find()` as it still says, "does not contain a definition for Find."

Comment: Since you said I can use LINQ to SQL, I will just use that.  Thanks for your help.  From what I gather, LINQ to SQL is what they use on this site and so it is still used in some significant capacity as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041011/is-linq-to-sql-deprecated

Comment: http://jinaldesai.net/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework/ Don't do XX because YY did this..

Comment: I think LINQ to SQL will support my needs based on the article you posted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice the date on that article.  It's from 2009.  That means it precedes Visual Studio 2010 and .net 3.5.  The article is talking about Entity Framework 1.0, which had a large number of problems, and thus it was often recommended to use Linq to SQL rather than EF 1.0.

However, as of VS 2010 and EF 4.0, most of those concerns were addressed and EF is now the preferred method over Linq to SQL.  L2S is still supported, but Microsoft is no longer doing any major improvements to it.

As others have mentioned in the comments, MVC is database agnostic.  You can use any database technology with it, and it is not dependent on EF in any way.  You can use EF, L2S, nHibernate, ADO.NET, etc...  You won't "break MVC" because MVC has no concept of your database technology.

Many people still implement repositories and Unit of Work on top of EF (although I personally see that as extra work unless you plan to need a database abstraction that allows you to change technologies).

EDIT:

Upon further reading of the article, I don't see anywhere where it recommends L2S over EF, in fact at the end of the article it has this comment:

> Suppose If you want to change the data access technology using  EF ( Entity Framework) instead of  LINQ TO SQL  you simply implement the IStudentRepository interface with a class that uses the alternative database access technology

Comment: EF, with it's visual designer, seems the same as LINQ to SQL.  Maybe I will just use it just in case it has something that LINQ to SQL doesn't have.  It seems like L2S will do everything I need, though...  Can't imagine anything I would need to do that it can't do.  Going to leave the question open for a while in case anyone else has something to add.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user1477388 - L2S has many limitations, for instance it doesn't support many to many joins directly.

Comment: Do you just mean if I wanted to do a join in LINQ, I would have to write a query like `from x in myTable join y in myOtherTable on x.a equals y.a`?

Comment: @user1477388 - no, that's not a many to many join.  A many to many uses a join table.  In EF, this can be represented as a single navigational property, whereas in L2S you have to query the Join table from two sides in a very ugly way.

Comment: Good to know.  I will probably just use EF since it doesn't really change my work flow versus LINQ.  I can still write LINQ queries, right?  Or does EF have it's own queries?

Comment: @user1477388 - yes, you can write linq queries, although there is a special EF query language if you wanted to use it.

Comment: Just tried using EF for like an hour; there is no interaction with the server explorer so I can't drag and drop any tables.  It just doesn't seem to have the ease of use that LINQ to SQL has.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you would rather the thing you spend the least time doing (creating new tables) is more important than the thing you spend most of your time doing (writing queries).  Umm.. ok, if that's what your priorities are.

Comment: No, I don't have any problems writing queries with LINQ; but I did just find out that I can't use MVC scaffolding with L2S...  Which slows me down quite a bit.

Comment: You're not getting my point.  Complex queries are hard to write in Linq to Sql, because L2S doesn't have as much functionality, so you spend more time writing queries in L2S than you do in EF.  Your complaint about being able to drag tables from Server Explorer is basically saying you prefer that over spending less time writing queries.  My comment was pointing out that you don't spend much time adding new entities to your model, but you spend lots of time writing queries, so why should dragging tables be so much more important than your query writing.

Comment: I do get your point, I simply haven't experienced the limitations of L2S.  I have done joins and many to many relations and I don't remember it being too difficult.